# Como formatar uma data no Harbour?

Tags: harbour

Estou aprendendo a linguagem [Harbour](https://harbour.github.io/). Eu estou vendo como essa linguagem trabalha com datas.

```
PROCEDURE MAIN()

    LOCAL date := Date()

    ? date

    RETURN
```

Isso está me retornando:

`02/10/21`

Como eu poderia fazer para formatar essa data para `DD/MM/YYYYY`, por exemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para alterar a apresentação default, usada no `?`, `SAY`, `GET` etc:

```
SET DATE german                      // Formatos pré definidos, legado
SET DATE FORMAT TO dd/mm/yyyy        // Formato customizável (pré processador)
Set( _SET_DATEFORMAT, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ) // Formato customizável (nativo)
```

Manual: https://harbour.github.io/doc/harbour.html#set-date-cmd

Para gerar uma string formatada:

```
hb_DToC( dData, cFormato )
```

Exemplo:

```
? hb_DToC( 0d20210531, 'DD~MM~YYYY' )
```

Saída:

```
31~05~2021
```

Se quiser o mesmo para um timestamp:

```
hb_TToC( tTimestamp, cFormatoData, cFormatoTempo )
```

Por falta de documentação detalhada, segue a implementação oficial:

- https://github.com/harbour/core/blob/master/src/rtl/dateshb.c
- https://github.com/harbour/core/blob/master/src/rtl/dates.c